# AWS Glue LAUNCH ERROR | java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: s3://py-function-bucket/aws_custom_functions.zip

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I've started to develop an ETL Job in AWS Glue using a notebook to verify the results of each step. When running one cell at the time, the job runs correctly. However, when using the run option for Glue, the following error appears:

**LAUNCH ERROR | java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0:
s3://py-function-bucket/aws_custom_functions.zip**

The magics I'm using to configure the notebook are as follows:

```
%extra_py_files  s3://py-function-bucket/aws_custom_functions.zip
%number_of_workers 2
%%configure
{
    "region": "region",
    "iam_role": "arn:aws:iam::glue_role"
    
}
```

This means that I have a bucket with a zip file that contains additional functions to use in the notebook, which they need to be imported.

I have tried using the full URL instead of the URI:

```
%extra_py_files  https://py-function-bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com/aws_custom_functions.zip
```

Shows the same error as before but with the full URL.

Finally I tried running the cell with the magics and deleting the cell. This only causes that the input argument for importing the additional functions is not passed and therefore causes error that the functions are not defined.

Anyone else having this issue? A work around would be declaring the functions in the notebook but this would mean doing the same for all Jobs I plan to develop.

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello. Sadly I haven't been able to solve it. I had to use the functions directly in the Notebook

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue. The problem is a space after the uri of the extra file that your as passing to `--extra-py-files`, so you just need to remove it like this:

> extra_py_files 's3://huma-dev-code/services/FeedConfiguration.py, s3://huma-dev-code/services/FeedConfiguration2.py'

You just need to remove the space between the comma and the second URI.

Sources:
https://dk521123.hatenablog.com/entry/2022/11/18/163207

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and managed to solve it.  In my scenario the issue was the declaration of this in the notebook:

```
extra_py_files 's3://huma-dev-code/services/FeedConfiguration.py'
```

for example, if I take the single quotes out:

```
extra_py_files s3://huma-dev-code/services/FeedConfiguration.py
```

Problem solved!  Weird that the notebook accepts the single quotes but the glue script/engine does not.